# POSIXlt error when importing datetime into R

Tags: r, datetime, rstudio

I'm importing a number of csv files into Rstudio, which have columns containing date and time (originally generated in pandas). The files import without any problem, but when I try to combine them with rbind, I get an error as follows:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I've tried setting the timezone but that doesn't work.

Below is the code showing the class and what the object looks like.

```
class(dd1$timestamp_datetime)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

glimpse(dd1$timestamp_datetime)
 POSIXct[1:10923], format: "2018-04-21 15:30:53" "2018-01-22 08:00:12" "2018-11-16 09:50:13" "2018-07-28 06:30:18" "2018-04-17 18:20:50"
```

The format looks ok to me, but not to R. I plan to use this dataset for time series analysis, so the datetime part is important. What should I do to make it work?

Update:
Here it is. Is it something to do with numbers all being different? They used to be the index when it was in pandas. Would dropping this row help?

```
 glimpse(dd1$X1)
 num [1:10923] 2 72 82 96 102 103 109 115 125 127 ...
> glimpse(dd2$X1)
 chr [1:74615] "0" "1" "6" "7" "8" "9" "10" "11" "12" "13" "15" "16" "18" "19" "20" "21" "23" "25" "26" "27" "28" "30" "34" ...
> glimpse(dd3$X1)
 chr [1:51843] "4" "6" "10" "13" "14" "15" "16" "22" "24" "27" "30" "33" "34" "35" "36" "38" "39" "41" "42" "49" "50" "51" ...
> glimpse(dd4$X1)
 num [1:48747] 2 3 5 7 9 12 17 18 20 21 ...
```

Additional code added:

```
dput(head(dd1))
structure(list(X1 = c(2, 72, 82, 96, 102, 103), text = c("RT @ThatTimWalker: Can’t help but think the hostile environment the Brextremists are creating is for themselves.", 
"RT @ThatTimWalker: The sad thing is if this country hadn’t been conned by Brextremists we’d be a very prosperous country now and respected…", 
"RT @Kevin_Maguire: Update on Brextremist monied elite:\nJames Dyson: Building factory in Singapore\nJim Ratcliffe: Moving to Monaco\nArron Ban…", 
"RT @ThatTimWalker: Why are the new revelations of dirty tricks and lies by the Brextremist groups during the EU Referendum considered stron…", 
"RT @EK_EuropeanMove: #Kipper #Leaver or #Brextremist hard to tell which cannot tell the difference between the extreme right nationalist id…", 
"RT @mrjamesob: May clearly thought that Brextremists would eventually be forced by the sheer weight of evidence &amp; events to acknowledge rea…"
), timestamp_datetime = structure(c(1524324653.333, 1516608012.083, 
1542361813.274, 1532759418.257, 1523989250.856, 1506776455.518
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), tweet_id = c(987715301230903296, 
955349361969393664, 1063368633320132608, 1023093269490790400, 
986308521280106496, 914112824942657536), keyword = c("brextremist", 
"brextremist", "brextremist", "brextremist", "brextremist", "brextremist"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), problems = structure(list(row = c(6721L, 
6722L, 6722L, 6723L, 6723L, 6723L, 8175L, 8176L, 8176L, 8177L, 
8177L, 8178L, 8178L, 8179L, 8179L, 8179L, 10805L, 10806L, 10806L, 
10806L), col = c(NA, "X1", NA, "X1", "timestamp_datetime", NA, 
NA, "X1", NA, "X1", NA, "X1", NA, "X1", "timestamp_datetime", 
NA, NA, "X1", "timestamp_datetime", NA), expected = c("4 columns", 
"a double", "4 columns", "a double", "date like ", "4 columns", 
"4 columns", "a double", "4 columns", "a double", "4 columns", 
"a double", "4 columns", "a double", "date like ", "4 columns", 
"4 columns", "a double", "date like ", "4 columns"), actual = c("2 columns", 
"#MacronPresident", "1 columns", , "861526132977434624", 
"3 columns", "2 columns", "Blame Remainers", "1 columns", "Blame Scotland", 
"1 columns", "Blame Ireland", "1 columns", "But never blame #PartybeforeCountry self serving #Brextremist  #Tories", 
"970756341433360385", "3 columns", "2 columns", "Ha..  You Brextremists are doing that brah.  Be an adult and accept the consequences of your decision", 
"803893962457153536", "3 columns"), file = c("'brextrem_only2.csv'", 
"'brextrem_only2.csv'", "'brextrem_only2.csv'", "'brextrem_only2.csv'", 
"'brextrem_only2.csv'", "'brextrem_only2.csv'", "'brextrem_only2.csv'", 
"'brextrem_only2.csv'", "'brextrem_only2.csv'", "'brextrem_only2.csv'", 
"'brextrem_only2.csv'", "'brextrem_only2.csv'", "'brextrem_only2.csv'", 
"'brextrem_only2.csv'", "'brextrem_only2.csv'", "'brextrem_only2.csv'", 
"'brextrem_only2.csv'", "'brextrem_only2.csv'", "'brextrem_only2.csv'", 
"'brextrem_only2.csv'")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

dput(head(dd2))
structure(list(X1 = c("0", "1", "6", "7", "8", "9"), text = c("@Bigandybruce @curtislauraj @davidschneider @daveleaper @Sean_x_Larkin The average remoaner has yet to have their b… , 
"RT @2tweetaboutit: Remoaner Emily Thornberry slapped down for trying to delay and complicate Brexit talks, 
"RT @henrybutcher56: #Marr Marrs reference to Vince Cable as “remoaner in chief” once more exposes the disgraceful BBC news editorial bias t…", 
"@jacquep @BrexitJustice Regarde:Not what remoaners want hear, more good news!", 
"RT @CllrBSilvester: Two traitors who think they know better than the 17.4m.\nThe arrogance of the #REMOANERS is breathtaking.\nIf they think…", 
"RT @arhselk: Great Tweet!Me thinks remoaner’s retweets will be as scarce as an unemployed financial expert living in London. “Project Pathe…"
), timestamp_datetime = c("2017-12-29 15:30:06.111", "2016-10-11 04:27:59.027", 
"2018-04-30 10:50:30.577", "2016-09-02 13:14:53.566", "2018-07-20 21:10:40.279", 
"2018-08-14 19:30:24.355"), tweet_id = c(946765274354765824, 
785698434561019904, 990906232268521472, 771697908789968896, 1020415718184153088, 
1029450182210015232), keyword = c("remoaner", "remoaner", "remoaner", 
"remoaner", "remoaner", "remoaner")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), problems = structure(list(
    row = c(106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 1785L, 1786L, 
    3166L, 3167L, 3168L, 6078L, 6079L, 6080L, 6106L, 6107L, 6108L, 
    6250L, 6251L, 6252L, 6253L, 8568L, 8569L, 8737L, 8738L, 8739L, 
    8740L, 8744L, 8745L, 8746L, 13232L, 13233L, 13234L, 14713L, 
    14714L, 15675L, 15676L, 15677L, 18672L, 18673L, 19735L, 19736L, 
    19737L, 19738L, 19739L, 19740L, 19773L, 19774L, 19775L, 20609L, 
    20610L, 20611L, 20774L, 20775L, 20776L, 23594L, 23595L, 23596L, 
    23597L, 24658L, 24659L, 26747L, 26748L, 26749L, 28388L, 28389L, 
    28390L, 28530L, 28531L, 28532L, 28533L, 28969L, 28970L, 30090L, 
    30091L, 30539L, 30540L, 30541L, 37020L, 37021L, 37620L, 37621L, 
    38702L, 38703L, 39489L, 39490L, 40052L, 40053L, 40054L, 40729L, 
    40730L, 40731L, 40732L, 41786L, 41787L, 42883L, 42884L, 42885L, 
    46803L, 46804L, 50709L, 50710L, 50711L, 51985L, 51986L, 52230L, 
    52231L, 52232L, 52233L, 54097L, 54098L, 54099L, 54100L, 54134L, 
    54135L, 54136L, 54137L, 54251L, 54252L, 54253L, 57349L, 57350L, 
    57848L, 57849L, 57850L, 58202L, 58203L, 58204L, 59773L, 59774L, 
    59775L, 59776L, 59861L, 59862L, 59863L, 59864L, 60008L, 60009L, 
    60010L, 60227L, 60228L, 60339L, 60340L, 60341L, 60342L, 61573L, 
    61574L, 61575L, 61576L, 61577L, 61578L, 65302L, 65303L, 65772L, 
    65773L, 68813L, 68814L, 70690L, 70691L, 70997L, 70998L, 71710L, 
    71711L, 71712L, 71713L, 72172L, 72173L, 72174L, 72175L, 72218L, 
    72219L, 72220L, 72221L, 74473L, 74474L, 74475L, 74476L), 
    col = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), expected = c("4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns"), actual = c("2 columns", 
    "1 columns", "1 columns", "1 columns", "1 columns", "3 columns", 
    "2 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", "1 columns", "3 columns", 
    "2 columns", "1 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", "1 columns", 
    "3 columns", "2 columns", "1 columns", "1 columns", "3 columns", 
    "2 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", "1 columns", "1 columns", 
    "3 columns", "2 columns", "1 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", 
    "1 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", 
    "1 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", 
    "1 columns", "1 columns", "1 columns", "1 columns", "3 columns", 
    "2 columns", "1 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", "1 columns", 
    "3 columns", "2 columns", "1 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", 
    "1 columns", "1 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", "3 columns", 
    "2 columns", "1 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", "1 columns", 
    "3 columns", "2 columns", "1 columns", "1 columns", "3 columns", 
    "2 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", 
    "1 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", 
    "3 columns", "2 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", "3 columns", 
    "2 columns", "1 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", "1 columns", 
    "1 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", 
    "1 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", 
    "1 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", 
    "1 columns", "1 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", "1 columns", 
    "1 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", "1 columns", "1 columns", 
    "3 columns", "2 columns", "1 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", 
    "3 columns", "2 columns", "1 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", 
    "1 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", "1 columns", "1 columns", 
    "3 columns", "2 columns", "1 columns", "1 columns", "3 columns", 
    "2 columns", "1 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", "3 columns", 
    "2 columns", "1 columns", "1 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", 
    "1 columns", "1 columns", "1 columns", "1 columns", "3 columns", 
    "2 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", 
    "3 columns", "2 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", "3 columns", 
    "2 columns", "1 columns", "1 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", 
    "1 columns", "1 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", "1 columns", 
    "1 columns", "3 columns", "2 columns", "1 columns", "1 columns", 
    "3 columns"), file = c("'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", "'remoan_only2.csv'", 
    "'remoan_only2.csv'")), row.names = c(NA, -177L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
>
```

Comment: The only sample data you've provided is from one frame, but you spoke of using `rbind`. If you're needing to rob-combine data, can you provide samples of the rows that fail? (The output you show above demonstrates that all data is correctly `POSIXt`.)

Comment: have added more data as requested... thanks for your help

Comment: As you said you have multiple csv files, can you select two of such files where you are facing an issue to `rbind` after importing them into R, post `dput(head(df1))` and `dput(head(df2))` here so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: ok, have added that data